# ASP.NET MVC AJAX POST 500 Internenal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I want to update the row but when I click the update buttton return json result that message "500 Internenal Server Error". I don't find the problem. Can you check the code?

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateInStock(int stokID, int amount, int uCost, int sumCost, string detail, string unit)
    {
        var model = db.tbl_InStock.Where(x => x.stockInID == stokID).FirstOrDefault();
        model.stockInAmount = amount;
        model.stockInCost = uCost;
        model.stockInSum = sumCost;
        model.stockInDetail = detail;
        model.stockInUnit = unit;
        //db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { result = "Redirect", url = Url.Action("Gelen", "Anasayfa") });
    }
```

I want to update the row but when I click the update buttton return json result that message "500 Internenal Server Error". I don't find the problem. Can you check the code?

```js
//Jquery Code
$("#uptInStock").click(function () {
        var no = $.trim($("#stokInIDD").val());
        var miktar = $.trim($("#amountt").val());
        var fiyat = $.trim($("#unitCostt").val());
        var toplam = $.trim($("#sumCostt").val());
        var detay = $.trim($("#detaill").val());
        var birim = $.trim($("#birimm option:selected").text());
        var obj = { stokID: no, amount: miktar, uCost: fiyat, sumCost: toplam, detail: detay, unit: birim };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'UpdateInStock',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8"',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.result == 'Redirect')
                    window.location = response.url;
                alert("Suc");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
//Html Code
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateInStock", "Anasayfa", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gelen Ürün - Güncelle</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="proIDD" />
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="stokInIDD" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only mb-4" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Miktar</label>
                        <div class="proUnit2 input-group mb-4">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">Miktar</div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amountt" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control mb-4" id="birimm" name="birim">
                            <option value="0">Birim Seçiniz</option>
                            <option value="1">Adet</option>
                            <option value="2">Bidon</option>
                            <option value="3">Koli</option>
                            <option value="4">Paket</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only mb-4" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Birim Fiyatı</label>
                        <div class="proUnit input-group mb-4">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unitCostt" placeholder="Birim fiyatı" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only mb-4" for="inlineFormInputGroup">Toplam Fiyatı</label>
                        <div class="proUnit input-group mb-4">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-try" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sumCostt" placeholder="Toplam fiyatı" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="detaill" placeholder="Açıklama" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                    <button id="uptInStock" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Kaydet</button>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I would use your debugger and step through your controller action to find out where exactly the 500 error is coming from. If you still need help, be sure and update your answer with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Please try your `url` with `Controller`,`Action`And `Area` if necessary. Below is some sample `url` you can try.

`url:"/Area/Controller/ActionName"`   (in your case UpdateInStock is your action name)
`url:"/Controller/ActionName"`

Or you can use `@Url.Action` with `razor` syntax.
`url:"@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")"`

Comment: Thank for your answer but I tried your both of two option. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was with the numbers with commas.

var fiyat = $.trim($("#unitCostt").val());
var toplam = $.trim($("#sumCostt").val());

These fields should be converted to float values.

var fiyat = **parseFloat**($.trim($("#unitCostt").val()));
var toplam = **parseFloat**($.trim($("#sumCostt").val()));